# How do I put a c lib on ubuntu to make extension to gcc?

Tags: compiling, gcc

I have a file named "h1.c", which contains this line of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

I can run this command

```
gcc h1.c
```

in any directory on Ubuntu, as Ubuntu puts the stdio.h file in /usr/include/stdio.h

I also have another file named "h2.c", which contains this line of code

```
#include "conio.h"
```

to run this command, `gcc h2.c`, successfully, I have to put "h2.c", "conio.h" and "conio.c" in the same directory or change that code to

```
#include "path/to/conio.h"
```

The third file to compile named "h3.c" contains this line of code

```
#include <conio.h>
```

To run `gcc h3.c` successfully, I can put "conio.h" and "conio.c" in "/usr/include/" directory. which works though, seems a little bit ugly as all other files are header files.

I guess the file "conio.c" can be put somewhere else. The question is, what directory should I put "conio.c", should I compile it first?

Answer (score 0):

Just save the header file(`.h` file) in the same directory where your code file is, and to use the header file in the code file, use `#include "header_file_name.h"` (I'm assuming your header file is `header_file_name.h`).

Also, if you put the `.h` file in some other directory, you might need to specify the whole path in `#include`.